# Porting from MySql to Redis

Tags: mysql, sql, caching, redis, nosql

This is probably more of a two part question, but the main focus is really how to port data from MySql into Redis.  I've read over [the process here][1] but its a bit over my head in terms of how that would work for my multi-colum set of data.  The end goal is that I would like to move over my activity feed from SQL to Redis.  From what I can tell, the best move is to store this data in a hash and then sort it using sorted sets.  The most common sort to start would just be created_at.

So the question is:

1) What is a fast way to port this over to SQL as via command line?

2) How could this be structured to sort via created_at?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Warning**: moving to Redis is not necessarily a good idea for you. Most of the time moving an entire MySQL database to Redis is a bad idea because MySQL let's you query much more loosely and makes it much easier to make complicated queries than Redis. I'll tell you how to move things over, but there's a good chance you only want to do this for some of your data (or maybe even not at all) for functionality that requires speed above all else.

So, assuming you need to make the switch while data is coming in live, you'll need to do a few things:

1. You'll want to start sending data to both MySQL and Redis and mark the rows that have been sent to both in some way (probably your updated_at column works fine for this-- just mark the time when you first started sending data to both).
2. Move all older data over to Redis. You can do this by writing a quick script in a language like Python that will just grab all data with `updated_at <= redis_start_date` and insert it into Redis. Now your Redis database should mirror your MySQL database exactly, and you can expect it to continue mirroring it into the future.
3. Make sure all appropriate APIs that used to rely on MySQL have new versions that work with Redis.
4. Test everything heavily and make sure the data in Redis matches what's in MySQL and is in the format you want, also make sure all appropriate APIs work with it, etc...

Once you're confident all these are set, just switch your live APIs to be the ones that use Redis and not MySQL. You can stagger this process switching them one at a time and verifying all is as it should be. Since data is being written to both MySQL and Redis, you can rollback at anytime in case something went wrong.

Once you've switched over everything and are confident it all works with Redis the way you want, turn off the code that's writing to MySQL and enjoy your fast new Redis database.

In terms of structuring this, it really depends on how you use it. If you just need to be able to look up individual items based on id and have them sorted based on created_at, you can use a sorted set of `(key = id; score=unix_time(created_at))` along with hashes of (id->column) for every other column. Again, this isn't something you necessarily want to do and it depends on your use case.

Comment: Good answer.  I actually solved the porting issue by writing a simple SQL query without having to go through a script first.  The benefit has been extreme speed.

As for redis itself, this will really only be for one table that controls an activity feed on our site.  Since most of this feed is served up via JSON and hit outside of our app, we wanted it to be as blazing fast and scalable as possible. 

I like the basic structure you have for sorted sets and really my only concern is performance of look ups.  We will test.